# JavaFX ComboBox TextField content upon keyevent

Tags: javafx, combobox, autocomplete

I am building a simple editable ComboBox with auto-complete. I want to filter the content of my ComboBox depending on the content of the inner TextField.
I managed to make it work, but I am facing an issue when it comes to re-applying the auto-complete logic when deleting a character from the TextField.

From what I saw, upon the key pressed event, the content of the text field does not contain yet the added character.
So I just made a simple logic to add the string version of the KeyEvent to simulate the content of the TextField. I made this beacuse I need to have the full text to apply my logic
Basically:

```
// In constructor
cmb.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(this::handleOnKeyPressed);

public void handleOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  String text = comboBox.getEditor().getText() + e.getText();
  // Filtering logic based on text
}
```

This works well when typing some characters, but when hitting the backspace or delete keys, it is not working (which is obvious as per the code).
So, the solution I would see would be to check the caret position and to simulate the backspace/delete character removal based on the caret postion. But this is quite cumbersome...
Hence I wonder if there is no other neater way to do this? Is it possible to get the full text directly? In the beginning I thought about adding a change listener, but seems not possible with the TextField.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You can add a listener to the `textProperty()` of the TextField.

Comment: Yes, indeed, answer validated below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ChangeListener<String>` to the `textProperty` of the editor, which will be triggered every time the text inside the editor field is changed:

```
cmb.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(this::handleComboTextChange);

...

public void handleComboTextChange(ObservableValue<? extends String> o, String oldText, String newText) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel so stupid... Of course you have to go through the text property for the listener...  
Thanks!